# If I'm using Atlassian Stash, can the git repo still be managed without using Stash?

Tags: git, bitbucket-server

I want to know if at some point, we decide to stop using Atlassian Stash, is it going to be possible to still access our git repos or will we be out of luck?

Comment: Are you hosting your own Stash server? Or are you using the cloud version? In both cases, I think the only solution to keep your repo is to clone them with the --mirror option. Please have a look to this link: https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking in to this a bit more, I've realized that you can't really just stop using Stash and continue to access the same repo on the same origin.  The origin of a repo checked out from a Stash server points to that Stash server which is what manages access to the repo.

If I want to stop using Stash, I simply need to change my origin and push the code to the new location.  This could be a git server on the same server that Stash was on or it could be a completely different server.  At that point, Stash will no longer be part of the equation.

Comment: One question, why do you want to stop using Stash? How will you manage your pull requests without Stash?

Comment: We have been using git + gitolite + arcanist to manage code reviews and things to this point.  We are actually going to do a test run on a project using Stash.  What we don't want is to get well into the project and realize that we don't want to use Stash but be stuck with it.

Answer (score 2):

Atlassian Stash uses just regular Git repositories, so if you remove Stash, just move your repositories to another repository manager to access them with HTTP (or move them to a folder, where you can access with a file:// path).